# Buck: platform_linker_flags

Tags: buck

How would one specify platform linker flags for:

- android
- Mac OS X x86_64
- Linux x86_64

in one cxx_library target?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
platform_linker_flags = [
  ('android', ['foo0', 'bar0']),
  ('macosx-x86_64', ['foo1', 'bar1']),
  ('linux-x86_64', ['foo2', 'bar2']),
],
```